# Set skip and limit in mongoose sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var comment = new Schema({
text: {type:String}
});

var Post = new Schema({
comments : [comment]
});
```

I have 'n' number of records for one post object and i want to retrieve the comment data based on limit and skip.

I want to add pagination for comment schema while populating comment data from Post model.

What is the approach to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

```
db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: [ 20, 10 ] } } )
```